# nnoremap with vnoremap

Tags: vim, nnoremap, indent

with vim, I use [object indent](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object).

and frequently I use this

```
vii:!sort
```

for sort a block with same indent.
I try set this nnoremap

```
nn <leader>ss vii:!sort<cr>
```

but don't work, any suggestion?

`ii` is a vnoremap for object-indent, maybe this is the problem, with `v`pass to visual mode and nnoremap don't continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `nmap`:

```
nmap <leader>ss vii:!sort<cr>
```

Because the plugin maps `ii` to some function call too, if you use `nnoremap` the `ii` mapping the plugin set is not followed.

Comment: I added `<cr>` but this don't is the problem

Comment: @juanpablo, yeah sorry I was too fast. Edited answer should work.

Comment: yeah! this working, but I scary to nmap :P